# When is the track "No differences" played?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

Track 01 on the [Aldnoah.Zero Original Soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/46499) is a vocal piece titled "No differences" ([lyrics](http://vgmdb.net/db/covers.php?do=view&cover=207415)). It's positively eargasmic. Thing is, I don't remember it being played at any point during the show (and, given that the lyrics are English, I feel like I would have remembered it if I had heard it). Was it used? If so, when?

(Yeah, I could just rewatch it and listen for the track, but that would take a few hours I don't want to spend right now.)

Comment: I read this first, then watched the whole series (for the first time) and I also didn't notice the song. However, I also can't find any official info on it not being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched the entire series again at 15-second interval. *No differences* was unused, not even a short part was played.

I later [found out](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/AwesomeMusic/AldnoahZero) that *No differences* and *AL℃-@* were cut songs. As mentioned further in their [link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CutSong), it is not to be confused with "Long Song, Short Scene" - songs played but with *very* minimal playtime, in which case I can attest no background music of this song was played anywhere in the series.

Comment: Well, I guess that settles that (specifically, that you went through and listened for it, which is far more reliable than an entry on TV Tropes). I sure hope they use those tracks in the second cour...

Comment: @senshin I actually realized how unfamiliar it sounded when I had just grabbed a copy of the A.Z OST. Re-checking with the intent to confirm was worse since they almost sounded similar.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like "No differences" shows up for the first time in episode 2 of the second cour (episode 14 overall) at around 19 minutes in. My ears explode with delight.

Comment: It's played again in Episode 21, around 12:30